Get Real Account Balance at Exchange via PineScript
I wonder if it's possible to get your account balance in PineScript?
So my strategy would refer to the real balance every time it starts a trade.
Initial capital has nothing to do with the real money - I'd like to trade some fixed % amount of the current balance.
Balance
